# Vue Js - mock the $http request using sinon modules

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs3, spy

In VueJs project I have list of api request methods in apiList.ts file with below code. Also I am trying to add the unit test case for getUsers, addUser, updateUser methods but unable to mock the http methods(get/post/put). Could someone help to add the test case for this below code.

File: apiList.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export const API_LISTS = {
    getUsers: () => {
        const apiUrl = `/get/users`;
        return Vue.prototype.$http.get(apiUrl);
    },
    addUser: (requestData: any) => {        
        let apiUrl = `/new/user`;
        return Vue.prototype.$http.post(apiUrl, requestData);
    },
    updateUser: (requestData: any) => {
        const url = `/update/user`;
        return Vue.prototype.$http.put(url, requestData);
    },
}
```

File: apiLists.spec.ts

```
    import { assert } from 'chai';
    import {API_LISTS } from 'apiList';
    
    describe.only('getUsers', () => {
    console.log("---------------------------------step-1");
    let axiosGetStub: any;
    const responseData = [{ id: 1, name: 'John' }, { id: 2, name: 'Jane' }];

    beforeEach(() => {
        console.log("---------------------------------step-2");
        axiosGetStub = sinon.stub(Vue.prototype.$http, 'get').callsFake(() => Promise.resolve({ status: 200, data: responseData }));
        console.log("---------------------------------step-3");
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        console.log("---------------------------------step-4");
        axiosGetStub.restore();
    });

    it('should call $http.get with the correct endpoint', async () => {
        console.log("---------------------------------step-5");
        await API_LISTS.getUsers();
        expect(axiosGetStub.calledOnce).equal(true);
        // expect(axiosGetStub.calledWith('/users')).equal(true);
    });

    it('should return the response data', async () => {
        console.log("---------------------------------step-6");
        const result = await API_LISTS.getUsers();
        console.log("---------------------------------step-7");
        // expect(result).equal(responseData);
    });
});
```

Output:
I am getting the logs step1, step2, step4 but **step3, step5, step6 and step7** not getting.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion: first i install chai and sinon with `npm`

```
npm install chai sinon --save-dev
```

after that i create a mock for http on before()

```
// Create a mock for $http
$httpMock = {
  get: sinon.stub(),
  post: sinon.stub(),
  put: sinon.stub(),
};

// Assign the mock to Vue.prototype.$http
Vue.prototype.$http = $httpMock;
```

And on beforeEach() reset the stbs before each test

```
$httpMock.get.reset();
$httpMock.post.reset();
$httpMock.put.reset();
```

After that you do this

```
it('API_LISTS.getUsers - should call $http.get with the correct URL', () => {
const expectedUrl = '/get/users';

// Invoke the getUsers method
API_LISTS.getUsers();

// Assert that $http.get was called with the expected URL
assert.isTrue($httpMock.get.calledOnceWith(expectedUrl));
});

it('API_LISTS.addUser - should call $http.post with the correct URL and data', () => {
const expectedUrl = '/new/user';
const requestData = { name: 'John', age: 25 };

// Invoke the addUser method
API_LISTS.addUser(requestData);

// Assert that $http.post was called with the expected URL and data
assert.isTrue($httpMock.post.calledOnceWith(expectedUrl, requestData));
});

it('API_LISTS.updateUser - should call $http.put with the correct URL and data', () => {
const expectedUrl = '/update/user';
const requestData = { id: 1, name: 'John' };

// Invoke the updateUser method
API_LISTS.updateUser(requestData);

// Assert that $http.put was called with the expected URL and data
assert.isTrue($httpMock.put.calledOnceWith(expectedUrl, requestData));
});
```

Good luck for you

Comment: I am getting the error - Cannot find name '$httpMock'.ts(2304)

Comment: Did you declare `let $httpMock: any;` at first, hope this help you